# How to restore deleted to-do's in Wunderlist?

Tags: wunderlist

This is what I did:

1. I went to https://www.wunderlist.com/#/lists/inbox (as a logged user).
2. I've unintentionally selected the first to-do's item.
3. I wanted to bookmark the page by <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> (in Chrome).

But instead of bookmark it, I've deleted the *to-do* item from that list.

I've gone to https://www.wunderlist.com/restore, but the list is empty.

How do I recover the removed item from the *Inbox*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Their restore function will only restore a deleted *list*. Similarly, if you overwrite a task's notes, there is [no getting them back](https://6wunderkinder.desk.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1935872-how-can-i-restore-deleted-lists-).

Where I've lost data from Wunderlist, I've found it propagated the deleting sync instantly across all of my mobile devices and desktop clients, meaning it couldn't be recovered there. In the end I managed to find an old phone that was powered off: I took it out of the building, out of Wi-Fi range, removed the SIM, and powered it on. It had the data and hadn't been able to sync the deletion. Phew. Good luck.